# Is there any way to print the object ref that called an instance/Static method, Using byte-code instrumentation

Tags: java-bytecode-asm

I read somewhere that when ever a method is called by "invokevirtual",
the object reference is fetched from the top of stack, followed by arguments.
I need to somehow print the object reference. Is it possible?

Comment: What’s that “the object ref that called …” of your title supposed to be? Why are you mentioning `static` methods in your title when you are referring to `invokevirtual` only in you question?

Comment: I was actually studying dynamic behavior of a class. and assuming that every method call in the java program gets converted to invokevirtual/invokestatic  in the bytecode. for example invokevirtual #38 where #38 refers to the  some ID in constant pool., so just wanted to know how the information about #38 can be retrived during the runtime.

Comment: Your comment is describing an entirely different thing than your question. Your question is about an object reference on the operand stack, whereas your comment is about an index into the constant pool embedded in the instruction. So we now have three nonmatching things, your title, your question and your comment. The answer to the latter is, you can find that information at the same place where you got the `#38` from.

Comment: I apologize for my inability to present the problem in perfect context. Let me try once again.  
I am working on an instrumentation based problem, where in i require to get information about the object that called the method.  For example if in java code there is a method call "emp1.getDetails()" where emp1 is an object of class employee.  
Now if i deassemble its class file using javap, i can identify this method call being represented by "invokeVirtual #3"  where # is referring to the object of type employee.  
Now the actual problem am facing is as follows

Comment: 1. I have implemented instrumentation interface, where in i have written all the code for instrumenting the byte code. but the method instructions that i get in this class are different that what is shown by javap. All i get here is the type of instruction "MethodInsnNode" and a lot of information associated with it but no information about the object associated with the call.   
 Note * the reference to javap tool is for the sake to explain what i need i.e. object id associated with the method call

Comment: `javap` does *not* print an object id. The number it prints is an index into the constant pool where information about the *method* can be found, which is the same information that ASM conveniently stored into the `MethodInsnNode`. That is, the declaring class, name and signature of the method. Because there is no information beyond the already provided, ASM doesn’t provide that index to you; it’s of no use. There is no such thing as an object id.

Comment: Won't two diff objects have different  # index. In constant pool...I guess they are different.

Comment: Again, *this index is **not** an object id*. This index describes the *method* and nothing else. And stop guessing.

Comment: okey... Thanks. Information was very useful

Comment: Is your (@amitkumar) question how to add some instructions on the bytecode level so that the receiver info of the invokevirtual invocation can be print at program runtime? If yes, there is a way to do it.  The number in javap's result is only an index; it is not any object reference..

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I want to do. I tried it by inserting a DUP instruction followed by invoking a static function that could print the object on top of stack . currently m stuck over how to pass the stack top(which wud b an object). Ljava/Lang/object doesn't work.... Kindly enlighten me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I'm not going to do it for you, because the actual code is annoying and tedious and if you're really genuinely interested you should learn how to do it yourself.  But I will attempt to be helpful and provide you with some direction.

Firstly, you're going to want to read the [ASM tutorials here](http://asm.ow2.org/).

The byte code format i'm going to write below comes from ASMIfier because it's much more clear.  I'm going to completely ignore javap because it's even more pedantic and detailed, but if you want to know what it is actually showing you, then you should read about the [Java ClassFile format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html).

Actually, you should do that first anyway, just to make sure that your background knowledge is somewhat filled out.

So, here's the nutshell of what you're going to want to do.  You're going to want to write a [ClassWriter](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html) that looks for instances of the INVOKEVIRTUAL opcode.

invokevirtual pops the values from the stack in reverse order, so last parameter first and the object you're invoking against last.  the #38 you are referring too is not the object, its a reference to the constant pool which contains a method name and method descriptor pair which is used as metadata because the JVM is typesafe.

Lets assume you have this code:

package sample;

```
public class JavaSimpleHelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

If you run [ASMIFier](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html#Q10) against it, you'll get something like this for just the main method ( cutting the context down for brevity )

```
  public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 6 L0
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    LDC "Hello World"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 7 L1
    RETURN
   L2
    LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L2 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```

so, you implement some sort of static dump method ( public static final dump( Object o ) )  , and write a class visitor that reorganizes your byte code.

You can use the method descriptor to figure out how deep in the pervious stack push instructions ( ALOAD, LDC,  ) you need to insert the the DUP/INVOKE to print your methods object target.  For example the Method Descriptor for System.out.println is [Ljava/lang/String;]V  Which means the method takes an array of Strings and returns void.  So you need to go 1 back in the stack to find the object target.  Your bytecode would, in turn, look like this:

Happy byte code twiddling.

```
  public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L0
    GETSTATIC java/lang/System.out : Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    DUP
    INVOKESTATIC my/staticutil/ClassThatDumps.dump (Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    LDC "Hello World"
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/io/PrintStream.println (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE args [Ljava/lang/String; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 1
```